# When to use "-ly" (scientific language)

Tags: adverbs

I'm wondering about what is the correct wording and in particular, which grammar rules are underlying your decision.

Some loci are expressed independent of the environment.

Some loci are expressed independently of the environment.

Thanks for your help!

Yamper

Comment: They're both fine. As OED says, ***independent*** is *Often used adverbially in phr. independent of (†on, †from) = **Independently of,** apart from, without regard to, irrespective of.* Idiomatically the simpler form is more common in your exact context.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @tchrist: I'm kinda thinking it *must* be a dup, but the best I could easily find was [“Love me tender”: adverb or adjective?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160418/love-me-tender-adverb-or-adjective), where one of the answers says [Moden English usage frequently uses an adjectival form where there should correctly be an adverbial form.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/160426/2637) Which may be good enough, but perhaps someone can find a better match.

Answer (score 2):

As per previous comment:

They're both fine. As OED says, independent is Often used adverbially in phr. independent of (†on, †from) = Independently of, apart from, without regard to, irrespective of.

Idiomatically the simpler form is more common in your exact context.