# Why does "this car is riding fastly" sound terribly awkward?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

I checked [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160418/love-me-tender-adverb-or-adjective) and [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/9724/adjective-or-adverb-unconsciously-vs-unconscious) answer, but it still unclear to me.

Let's say

> This car is fast (slow, careful, lazy)
>   Here fast/slow definitely is adjective, it describes the car.

But if we modify the sentence in this way

> This car is riding slowly (carefully, lazily)

the 'slowly' is an adverb, because related to verb 'riding', correct? Then why

> This car is riding fastly

sounds terribly awkward? What should be used here and why?

Comment: First, you probably want to replace "riding" with "driving" or simply "going". Cars don't *ride*, though *people* can certainly ride in cars. Second, the last example is awkward because *fast* is both the adjective and the adverb. There is no \**fastly*. But you could use *quickly*, and it would be just as acceptable as *slowly* (as opposed to *quick*, which would put off some pedants).

Comment: PS: I think this question is fine here, it's well-researched and well-presented, but you might also like to check out our sister site, dedicated to helping people learn English as a foreign language: [ELL.se]. It's friendly, fun, and full of great teachers.

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/602308/2085).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question very simply, *fastly* is unfortunately not a word! According to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, the proper adverb is simply *fast*.

> He ran as *fast* as he could.

You could of course use "quickly" instead.

You also might want to consider changing "riding" to "moving," simply because *to ride* is a transitive verb.

Best of luck to you! —C.T.

Comment: 'Ride' can be used without an object. However it does mean that the car is being carried (quickly) by something else, which is probably not what is meant.